# How to use pillow to put an image into python?

Tags: python, image, user-interface

```
def get_image(image_name: str, size: tuple[int, int], cache: dict[str, ImageTk.PhotoImage] = None) -> ImageTk.PhotoImage:
    """ Returns the cached image for image_id if one exists, otherwise creates a
        new one, caches and returns it.

    Parameters:
        image_name: The path to the image to load.
        size: The size to resize the image to, as (width, height).
        cache: The cache to use. If None, no caching is performed.

    Returns:
        The image for the given image_name, resized appropriately.
    """
    if cache is None or image_name not in cache:
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.open(image_name).resize(size))
        if cache is not None:
            cache[image_name] = image
    elif image_name in cache:
        return cache[image_name]
    return image
```

How can I use this function in order to put an image into my GUI

I tried

```
header_image = self.get_image("header.png", (1760, 409))
header_photo = tk.PhotoImage(header_image)
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com).
[\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start. Where / how do you want to put the image?

Comment: Your function `get_image()` seems to already return a `ImageTk.PhotoImage` so you should already have what you want without further ado.